# How to add NOT to from validation pattern in Angular

Tags: angular, validation

In TS I have variable which contains regex, f.e.

```
public regex = /[a-z]/;
```

in HTML we have something like this

```
<input ngModel="" [pattern]="regex" />
```

It means it will validate our input according to regex. The only a-z chars are acceptable.

I don't want to change regex and say something like "All chars are acceptable except a-z", do you have any idea how to do that?

thanks.

Comment: `I don't want to change regex...` <= why not? Changing the regex would make the most sense in this case.

Comment: Actually, I have regex with special symbols which are not allowed to add

But to pattern I need to pass symbols which are ALLOWED :)

Comment: ah, sorry. Solution is found.

[^a-z]

Comment: So your solution was to change the regex even after saying that you didn't want it to change?

Comment: yes,

Actually my expression is 
/[~!^*+=\\\{\}|`;:'/?<>]/g

But how to exclude these symbols, 

I thought /^[~!^*+=\\\{\}|`;:'/?<>]/g, but it doesn't work